# Type '(number | Auth0User[])[]' is missing the following properties from type '[Auth0User[], number]': 0, 1

Tags: node.js, typescript, auth0

I am getting a list of users from the Auth0 api, and returning the users along with the totalNumber of users.

This is my code:

```
public async getAuth0Users(params): Promise<[Auth0User[], number]| null> {
  return managementAPI
      .getUsers(queryParams)
      .then((users) => {
        let auth0Users = users.users.map((r) =>
          Auth0ManagementApiService.rowToAuth0User(r),
        );
        let totalCount = users.total;
        return [auth0Users,totalCount];
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.loggerService.error(
          { errMsg: error.toString(), err: error },
          'getAuth0Users',
        );
        throw error;
      });
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Type '(number | Auth0User[])[]' is missing the following properties from type '[Auth0User[], number]': 0, 1
```

I am returning `[auth0Users,totalCount]` where `auth0Users` is an array and `totalCount` is a number. What is wrong?

Comment: just wondering what will the error be if you write:
let res = [auth0Users,totalCount]; return res;

Comment: Is is the same error

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mAVaZW), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing, as-is without unrelated errors. This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: I presume the issue is TypeScript's default inference of array literals being array types instead of tuple types.  You can probably write `let res: [Auth0User[], number] = [auth0Users, totalCount]; return res;` and it will work.  But I would love to see a [mcve] so I could test this myself before answering.